# SQLDataReader sort order versus Stored procedure order

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure that has `ORDER BY` clause for returning my records.
When I execute in SQL I see appropriate order.

However when I execute from the client and load into a `SqlDataReader`, the order has changed.  It's not the expected result. I get the same records, but the order (or maybe columns it's ordering on) has changed.

What could be manipulating this? Or, what can I do in order to apply `ORDER BY` on the Reader at the client?

The final SELECT out of the SP is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
     TotalMatchCount 
    ,ExampleDescription as Description 
    ,ExampleMatchCount 
    ,ExampleLevenshtein 
    ,Code6 as Code
    ,Tier1Code 
    ,Tier1Description 
    ,Tier1MatchCount 
    ,Tier1Levenshtein 
    ,Tier2Code 
    ,Tier2Description 
    ,Tier2MatchCount 
    ,Tier2Levenshtein 
    ,Tier3Code 
    ,Tier3Description 
    ,Tier3MatchCount 
    ,Tier3Levenshtein 
FROM  
    @SearchResults 
Order by 
     ExampleMatchCount Desc 
    ,ExampleLevenshtein ASC 
    ,Tier3MatchCount DESC 
    ,Tier3Levenshtein ASC 
    ,Tier2MatchCount DESC 
    ,Tier2Levenshtein ASC 
    ,Tier1MatchCount DESC 
    ,Tier1Levenshtein ASC
```

Where a Result might be (only giving main description fields):

`getting hh child ready for school
 helping hh child with a school project
 waiting for school bus with hh child
 etc.`

On the client calling to SP:

```vb
Private SearchRDR As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Dim db As DBAccess = New DBAccess
Dim rdr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    Try
        db.AddParameter("@pSearchText", _SearchText)
        rdr = db.ExecuteReader("sprc_SEL_Search")

        If rdr.HasRows Then
            'Get the data into the reader object
            SearchRDR = rdr
```

At this point I have checked the values in the `rdr` and they are already out of order. But in my code, when I go to load a data gridview I pull the `rdr` from its class and load the values:

```vb
Dim rdr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
rdr = cSearch.SearchRDR

Try
    If rdr.HasRows Then

        While rdr.Read()
            dgvSearch.Rows.Add(rdr("mycolumn").ToString() 
. . . . . . . .
```

But as stated, it was already out of order before it got here. The results I see would similar to:

`waiting for school bus with nonhh child
 dropping off nonhh child at friend's house
 waiting for school bus with hh child`

Which is not the order shown above.  In fact the first item from SQL shows up in the reader at approximately position 4 (row 4).  Then second SQL items appears at Row 6.

Ultimately there is NO alteration of order on the client.  It is just not using the order specified at the server.

Comment: Please post the code, the desired results, and the actual results you are getting.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause in the stored procedure will affect the order that they are read by the `SqlDataReader`.  If it's not working that way, that would be an unexpected behavior and it would be impossible to diagnose without a working example of code which duplicates the behavior.

Comment: Reader doesn't change order of records. What do you mean by "final select"? Stored procedure can have many selects and they all will be passed to reader. You can access them by `reader.NextResult`. So, may be you accessing wrong result, if you have multiple `selects`?

Comment: At the point where you check the order of rows in the reader and they are already wrong, but before you start reading the result... that's just not possible. It's not that I doubt you're getting the wrong order. It's not possible because a datareader _doesn't have rows to check._ It just reads rows from the server _one at a time_ until there are no more to read. It only models a single record and an iterator.

Comment: In cases like this, many times, you may be, simply connected to a different database, or in your case - table, when you testing your app vs executing SP directly. I've just seen this too many times to disregard that possibility.

Comment: >simply connected to a different database
Nope.  Brand new SP that only exists in my development Database.  No possible way to be hitting wrong DB or wrong SP.

Comment: > It just reads rows from the server one at a time...datareader doesn't have rows to check
While that may be true, @ Server my results show in the order expected.
When I Debug/Breakpoint and stop in the code above...either in my processing loop...right after WHILE rd.Read() or if testing it ...by doing a read() immediately after the SP call/rdr HasRows, the first row returned in the read...is NOT the same row that the direct exection of the stored procedure shows.

Comment: >What do you mean by "final select"?
By Final I mean my select from my table variable for return to the client.
Although I do no other explicit SELECTS i checked @ client with .NEXTRESULT and there is NOT another result.

Comment: >Reader doesn't change order of records.
This would be why I'm perplexed.  I've used this methodology plenty of times and NEVER had an issue.

As a test yesterday I even created a brand new table variable with a rowid identity, INSERTED my results into that...then selected for return to client BY the identity column.   Same results.  SP looked fine.  Client jumbled rows.

Comment: FYI...
I went back even to my DataAcess Class call(code below)
AND executed.  Then immediately did a READER.READ() and in immediate window printed out results.
The reader showed me not the first, but the (incorrect) 7th record that my sQL brings back.

   Public Function ExecuteReader(ByVal commandtext As String) As IDataReader
        Dim reader As IDataReader = Nothing
        Try
            cmd.CommandText = commandtext
            reader = Me.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Todd, if you want to sent message to specific user, you have to type @userName. `>` <-- this doesn't work and unless users will specifically open your question, they will never know that you wrote something to them. You see how many responses you got - 0

Comment: Thanks. @T.S.  (had no idea).

Comment: I think, I understand your problem. Table variable is your problem. It changes the order. I've seen this. You need to post your SP. when you fill it, and it has indexes, it reorganizes your order

Comment: @todd - maybe you could try this : use an SqlDataAdapter to fill the results in a new DataSet. Serialize the dataset to xml, then post that here.

Comment: @todd - another idea. What if you change your order by clause, so that it returns the REVERSE order to what you currently see (in SSMS).  Then, execute this query from ado.net. What ordering do you see ? e.g. is it the REVERSE ordering of your original ado.net ordering, or does it still appear to be random ? It may help to find a pattern.

Comment: @moesisko. This issue wound up being the parameter being passed in.  I had accidentally left off the .TOSTRING so it was pushing thru the textbox Object, who evaluate to a much longer string.  Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

ADO DB objects have a built in RowFilter and Sort property which can be applied directly to the SQLDataReader object prior to assigning the object to an array.  So, even if the SQL Stored Procedure isn't returning the rows in the expected order, you can achieve the proper order after getting the record-set returned from the ADO DB object.

```
rdr.Sort = "ExampleMatchCount Desc"
```